# Is there syntax sugar for passing child as template with ref to component in angular (2+)

Tags: angular

I currently looking for a way to cut the noise when passing templates to angular components.

Consider the following code:

```
<parent>
  <ng-template #child1><div>Test</div></ng-template>
  <ng-template #child2><div>Test</div></ng-template>
</parent>
```

Is it possible to create a structural directive that can be used more or less like this?

```
<parent>
  <div *asTemplate="#child1">Test</div>
  <div *asTemplate="#child2">Test</div>
</parent>
```

so that

```
<div *asTemplate="#child1">Test</div>
```

desugars to

```
<ng-template #child1><div>Test</div></ng-template>
```

Directly using

```
<div *asTemplate #child1>Test</div>
```

doesn't work because the ref "child1" references the div and not the template.

Thx a lot!

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by using a template reference?

Comment: I'm just looking for a nicer way to pass templates to components. I can reference them easily with `@ContentChild('child1') myChild` when they are wrapped in an ng-template with a ref. As i said the first example code works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easily thing to do is pass templates as input bindings. It allows you to define multiple inputs, and doesn't require anything complicated inside the component to render them.

```html
<parent [itemA]="childA" [itemB]="childB"></parent>
<ng-template #childA>Test A</ng-template>
<ng-template #childB>Test B</ng-template>
```

Templates are structurally independent from the HTML. The only reason you would need to position the `<ng-template>` inside a Html element is to access a scoped template variable. Otherwise, it doesn't matter where in the template you place the `<ng-tempalte>`.

> Is it possible to create a structural directive that can be used more or less like this?

You can use structural directives to *forward* template references to a parent component using the dependency injector. You would inject the parent, and then call a method on the parent to forward a reference.

```html
<parent>
   <div *child></div>
</parent>
```

Where the *child* directive will pass the template reference to the parent using a function callback (i.e. `setChildTemplate`)

```js
@Directive({selector: '[child]'})
export class ChildDirective implements OnDestroy {
    constructor(tempRef: TemplateRef<any>,
                private parent: ParentComponent) {
       this.parent.setChildTemplate(tempRef);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
       this.parent.setChildTemplate(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, i already know that i can do it this way. Setting the template from the child is not really what i'm looking for because it means the child needs to know the type of the parent. I will still upvote your answer because i feel there is no way to achieve exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: @frabbit the first approach then is the only way that I know of. That is how templates work in Angular, and you mentioned "noise" referring to boilerplate code as an issue. I don't think there is an easier way.